# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId.newInstance()Lio/netty/channel/DefaultChannelId;

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, aws-sdk, playframework-2.5

I am trying to use `"software.amazon.awssdk" % "dynamodb" % "2.10.33"`
with my project on **Play framework (Java)**.

Following is a brief of the project configuration

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.14")
sbt.version=0.13.8
```

Tried excluding netty dependency from the new package

```
("software.amazon.awssdk" % "dynamodb" % "2.10.33").excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization =  "io.netty"))
```

The project worked fine with

```
"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-core" % "1.10.52",
"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3" % "1.10.52",
"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-dynamodb" % "1.10.52"
```

Upgrading to the new AWS library seems to break the project. `sbt compile` returns success
However, `sbt run` results in the aforementioned error.

> 

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId.newInstance()Lio/netty/channel/DefaultChannelId;


[info] Running the application with Aspectj Weaver
--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId.newInstance()Lio/netty/channel/DefaultChannelId;
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.newId(AbstractChannel.java:100)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.<init>(AbstractChannel.java:72)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.FailedChannel.<init>(FailedChannel.java:33)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister(AbstractBootstrap.java:308)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.doBind(AbstractBootstrap.java:260)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.bind(AbstractBootstrap.java:227)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer.bind(NettyServer.scala:139)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer.play$core$server$NettyServer$$bindChannel(NettyServer.scala:224)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$1.apply(NettyServer.scala:216)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$1.apply(NettyServer.scala:216)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer.<init>(NettyServer.scala:216)
        at play.core.server.NettyServerProvider.createServer(NettyServer.scala:279)
        at play.core.server.NettyServerProvider.createServer(NettyServer.scala:278)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:235)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:65)
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.mainDev(DevServerStart.scala:64)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.mainDevHttpMode(DevServerStart.scala:54)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart.mainDevHttpMode(DevServerStart.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at play.runsupport.Reloader$.startDevMode(Reloader.scala:234)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.devModeServer$lzycompute$1(PlayRun.scala:74)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.play$sbt$run$PlayRun$$anonfun$$anonfun$$anonfun$$devModeServer$1(PlayRun.scala:74)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:100)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:53)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
```

Attached dependency tree:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dVf8aJiv2i0Tscn2XEhETQ-ae3dgqfHk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use two incompatible versions of Netty. That is impossible.

Upgrading to Play 2.6 or later would solve this for two reasons:

1. Play 2.6 uses akka-http as server by default
2. Netty in Play 2.6 is shaded, so you can use another library which depends on Netty in your project

---

edit: the AWS SDK uses Netty only as its default http client, which can be replaced.

```scala
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "software.amazon.awssdk" % "dynamodb" % "2.10.33" exclude("software.amazon.awssdk", "netty-nio-client")
)
```